# How to match 'Scanner' with 'LenthOfString' to work together?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner with java and I have problems with very basic functions, i don't understand them well and I am only a first year computing student. I have a big project to do so please just help me with re-arranging my code I have so far. I am trying to make the code count the string length of the text entered to a scanner box. But I have played with the code and I don't really know how to change the layout of my code to match the scanner and lengthOfString and not mess up the code. I know my question is very easy for you so please help me, the code i have so far is underneath:

```
import java.util.*; 

public class LengthOfString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

        System.out.println(lengthOfString("I need your help programmers, please"));
    }

    private static int lengthOfString(String string) {
        int length = -1;

        while (true) {
            try {
            string.charAt(++length);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return length;
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String`s have a `length()` method for that.

What about something in the lines of...

```
// prompt
System.out.println("Type your text...");
// scanner initialization
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
// getting next line by user, then getting the length and printing it
System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length());
// once we're done with the Scanner...
sc.close();
```

**Output**

```
Type your text...
foo
3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your code suggestions, I added them to my code and I play around with them, i also did some more research about the 'length()' method. One error appeared which I can't solve but I'm going to create a different question about it, thank you for your help again!